# Scaling ratio in Android images?

Tags: android, image, scaling

I am developing a simple informative system which will use a lot of images. The problem is I do not know how to scale them to the folder of ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and hdpi.

I read that android uses a scaling ratio like 3:4:6:8. Can some explain to me what is this **3:4:6:8 scaling ratio**? How do I use it, and what is the logic behind it?

Suppose I have a 50x50 px image in **ldpi** folder. If I am going to use *3:4:6:8 ratio*. What will be the next image size for my **mdpi** folder and **hdpi** folder?

Please help. I dont realy understand that scaling ratio. Sorry for this, I'm only a newbie in android design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly they use these standard sizes:

ldpi: 36*36 
mdpi: 48*48
hdpi: 72*72
xhdpi: 96*96

Comment: if the image is 36*36 then how did it become 48*48? did you multiply it?? by what number?

Comment: ldpi/mdpi=3/4    => 4*ldpi=3*mdpi;  => if ldpi=36 => mdpi*3=4*36 => mdpi=144/3=48;   Similarly, mdpi/hdpi=4/6 => 6*mdpi=4*hdpi and so on....

Comment: so mdpi = (4/3)*ldpi;   hdpi = (6/4)*mdpi ; xhdpi = (8/6)* hdpi; This way can relate all the resolutions to each other.

Comment: so it means that 3:4:6:8 is 3/4/6/8?

Answer (score 1):

Its so simple.

If image size is 50*50 for Ldpi then:

> MDPI => 67*67
>
> HDPI => 100*100
>
> XHDPI => 125*125

Comment: thank you for your answer. can u please explain how did it happen?? what is the formula of that?

Comment: Im sorry. For me that is not simple. How did you get the 67x67 size from 50x50? please tell? T_T

Comment: @nelzkie If 3 is having 50 then what is for 4? so Equation is like (50*4)/3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple [tool](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/) to figure out the conversions. it doesn't have the xxhdpi, but you can easily modify it to calculate it for you