# Custom shaped Linearlayout with curved side in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-shape

I am trying to make a custom shaped linearlayout like below

[image]

I am trying to make only one side curved. Tried with corner radius but it doesn't give the same look as above.

Already tried this background shape as below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

it rounds only corners and on increasing the value shape is not preserved it gets too circular. I WANT CURVED line and not rounded corners

Comment: You  can create image with this curved shade and can add as background of `Layout`.

Comment: i am not sure if it will look the same on all resolutions so i avoided that. will it?

Comment: You can use dimen for all Resolutions and made it work easily.

Comment: @SumeetDarade are you able to fix the issue ?? and how you are doing this?

Answer (score 13):

Its very late already but this is for future seekers.
I think [vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) are the most perfect solution for this. Use below vector [as background](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88) to get custom shaped bottom curved layout.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="100.0"
android:viewportWidth="200.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#YOUR_FAVORITE_COLOR"
    android:pathData="M200,0H0v4.5h0v75.8h0c17.8,10.2 56,17.2 100.5,17.2c44.5,0 81.6,-7 99.5,-17.2h0V4.5h0V0z" />
```

Comment: Used this with ImageView scaleType=fitXY

Answer (score 10):

Create a shape file in drawable folder e.g: my_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
      android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
   <padding
      android:bottom="0dp"
      android:left="0dp"
      android:right="0dp"
      android:top="0dp" />
   <stroke
      android:width="0.5dp"
      android:color="@color/theme_red" />
  <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

then add this shape in your layout as a background. e.g:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
     android:orientation="horizontal">             
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: as i said i tried adding radius.it does not look like the shape in image. i want line to be curved

Comment: I think you should go with background image. First you design an image as your requirement. then use it as background in your layout

Comment: Yes, can you suggest any resolution to  begin with which will look same on all devices?

Comment: You should start your image design from mdpi screen then design rest of the screen like hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc and must follow the screen design ration. follow this [Link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and  [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167537/scaling-ratio-in-android-images)

Answer (score 8):

shape_curve.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="-80dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Use

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_curve"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 5):

what i did is
create a drawable `allowaccess_button_normal.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Try below layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#fefefe"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="110dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/allowaccess_button_normal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 <layer-lisxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item  android:top="175dp">

    <shape android:shape="oval">

     <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:startColor="#f56f2c"
        android:endColor="#fa9f46"/>

   </shape>
  </item>


  <item android:bottom="40dp">

   <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:startColor="#f56f2c"
        android:endColor="#fa9f46"/>

   </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the dimension in the value -dimension.xml fime and then set it in your xml of your linearlayout it will give the following like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
   android:color="#FFFF00" />
<padding android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="7dp" />
```

just make a xml file in your drawable set the dimensio u need and then call it by your linear layout

Comment: sorry for not getting it but can you give a example ?  am not sure what dimensions you talking about